# What does ‘general ideas’ mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have looked up [Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/) but I still don’t get it!

[image: general ideas]

Comment: I can't find any relevant page with a site-specific search for "general ideas" on https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/. It seems unlikely to me that they would say the ordinary plural noun ***newspapers*** is an example of article-less usages generally involving abstract/uncountable "concepts".

Comment: Please don't make the entire body of your question one giant image.  Images can't be searched, and they're unfriendly to users with vision problems or on slow internet connections.

Answer (score 1):

A general idea: music. A specific idea: the music of Mozart.

A general idea: exams. A specific idea: the exam I sit tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It suggests that you can't use it when making generalisations; for instance:

- I like music. (General fact.)
- I like the music. (= which music?)